# How to disable Area routes on main routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

// global.asax route

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
new string[] { "MyApplication.Controllers" } // Controller Namespace
);
```

// Area Registration Route

```
context.MapRoute(
MyArea_default,
"MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
new string[] { "MyApplication.Areas.MyArea.Controllers" }
);
```

when I go to http://mydomain.com/controler_in_area still work.
how to disable http://mydomain.com/controler_in_area, I just want work as http://mydomain.com/MyArea/controler_in_area

Answer (score 2):

i have tried with your code its work for me.
see below screenshot.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Register MyArea_default route before Default route. Routes are matched first match first served.